# combine "url" tag with "bootstrap_button" tag?

Tags: django-templates, django-bootstrap5

I can't get this incantation right.  I want a button that acts like a link.

I'm using django-bootstrap5, which has a nice `{% bootstrap_button %}` tag.  But I can't figure out how to use django's `{% url %}` tag to supply the `href` value.

This clearly won't work...it won't even parse

```
  {% bootstrap_button button_type="link" content="Create Report" href="{% url 'report:create' %}" %}
```

So I tried this, but the link in the button ends up being the literal "create_url"

```
  {% url 'report:create' as create_url %}
  {% bootstrap_button button_type="link" content="Create Report" href="{{create_url}}" %}
```

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{create_url}}" role="button">Create Report</a>
```

there has to be a way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into this same issue. Try adding a template variable before the button as you did:

```
{% url 'the-link' as the_link %}
{% bootstrap_button "The Button" button_type="link" button_class="btn-success" href=the_link %}
```

And then only reference the variable name without brackets.